# Spacy Remove stopwords without affecting Named Entities

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to remove stopwords from a string but the condition I want to achieve is that the named entities in the string should not be removed.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "The Bank of Australia has an agreement according to the Letter Of Offer which states that the deduction should be made at the last date of each month"
doc = nlp(text)
```

If i check the named entities in the text, i get the below

```
print(doc.ents)
(The Bank of Australia, the Letter Of Offer, the last date of each month)
```

The usual way to remove the stopwords would be like below

```
[token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
['Bank',
 'Australia',
 'agreement',
 'according',
 'Letter',
 'Offer',
 'states',
 'deduction',
 'date',
 'month']
```

The normal way completely took the meaning away which is needed for my task.
I would want to retain the Named Entities.

I tried adding the named entities with the same list.

```
list1 = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
list2 = [str(a) for a in doc.ents]

list1 + list2

['Bank',
 'Australia',
 'agreement',
 'according',
 'Letter',
 'Offer',
 'states',
 'deduction',
 'date',
 'month',
 'The Bank of Australia',
 'the Letter Of Offer',
 'the last date of each month']
```

Is there any other approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on the token level whether it's part of an entity, using `token.ent_iob_` or `token.ent_type_`, cf the [API documentation](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes). So you probably want something like this:

```
print([token.text for token in doc if token.ent_type_ or not token.is_stop])
```

which returns

> ['The', 'Bank', 'of', 'Australia', 'agreement', 'according', 'the', 'Letter', 'Of', 'Offer', 'states', 'deduction', 'the', 'last', 'date', 'of', 'each', 'month']

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in this case I'm losing the tokens "The Bank of Australia", "Letter Of Offer" and "Last date of each month" as a whole and have only split tokens.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but keep in mind that "The Bank of Australia" is not a token, it's a multi-token entity. So if I understand what you're trying to do, I would merge the non-stop and non-entity tokens with the `doc.ents`.